# Simple MySQL Query returning invalid result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying simply to select the products that fall within a price range, in this case between $160 and 200. The query seems normal, but its also including products with the price of $123.

```
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE  name LIKE '%test%' 
AND  price >= '160' AND  price <= '200' AND  1=1
LIMIT 50
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you using  AND 1=1 ?

Comment: Why are you converting numbers to string?

Comment: 1=1 is being used because the query is being built dynamically, so I need to have that at the end otherwise there will always be an 'AND' at the end.

Comment: You are probably comparing numbers with strings (quotes numbers in your code). Don't do it, it's not PHP.

Comment: Don't use LIKE `'%test%'` with `price >= '160' AND  price <= '200'`
Try between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use `BETWEEN`?

```
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE  name LIKE '%test%'  AND  
        price BETWEEN 160 AND 200
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `price`?

Comment: @clickupvoteThe ' are for string data, the reason you're getting 123 is that price is doing an ASCII compare of string data.